# The meaning of the following Sentence --- "Learning disabilities are immutable irrespective of time and nature of interventions"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence, ambiguity

Can anyone please explain to me the meaning of the following sentence?

> Learning disabilities are immutable irrespective of time and nature of interventions.

I am also not sure whether the structure of the sentence is correct.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A bit too much academic speak.  A simpler phrasing may be 'Learning disabilities are unable to be changed regardless of the time and nature of interventions' - basically, they are never fully curable.

Comment: It means the guy's never been to an optometrist.

Comment: @HotLicks Short-sightedness (or even blindness) is not usually classified as a learning disability, even if it can make learning more difficult (if the blackboard is too far away).

Comment: @MartinBonner - OK, so what about "dumb", as in "deaf and dumb"?

Comment: @HotLicks "dumb" is not a medical diagnosis.  People who are profoundly deaf from birth are often unable to speak because they can't hear what they are saying (the profoundly deaf *can* be taught to speak though).  That is not a learning disability.  (They can communicate with sign language.)  On the other hand, there are people who have disabilities which are both physical (like deafness), and and mental.  The mental disabilities might mean they are unable to be taught to communicate.

Comment: @MartinBonner - For centuries deaf people were thought to be mentally retarded, hence the use of the term "dumb" to mean "stupid".  Often disabilities are a self-fulfilling diagnosis.

Comment: @HotLicks That is true, but what does it have to do with the sentence in the question which is clearly referring to modern definitions of "learning disabilities" rather than historical "idiots".

Comment: @MartinBonner - Many kids with the physical features of Down's syndrome have bone structure issues which lead to deafness.  This in turn can lead to poorer mental/social development, even though their IQ is essentially "normal".  Early intervention to correct the hearing defects can make a substantial difference in the outcome of this "disability".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"immutable" = "cannot be changed"

"interventions" = various therapies, drugs, tutoring, etc.

"irrespective" = (in this case) "regardless" or "despite"

So:

> It doesn't matter what treatments are tried (or when), someone with a learning disability will always have that learning disability.

Note that this *doesn't* mean interventions are pointless.  Most learning disabilities are of the form "it is much more difficult to learn something", and not of the form "it is impossible to learn something".  Teaching someone to learn to read and write may take longer, but is still worthwhile.